ClickOnce Application via Remote Desktop Application rendering in DPI_unaware mode
Created remote desktop application which calls the clickonce application.
Remote desktop application is unable to open in the scale present initially, it always opens with 100% scale even if the display properties scale is set to 125%.
When we change the scale in display properties from 125% to 150% and back it renders properly.
Expecting Clickonce application to scale properply based on scale present in display properties.

show code and settings
